# agent{} equivalent command in jenkins scripted pipeline to use docker container as slave agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins declarative pipeline, I have seen following code used to build project in a docker container as build agent.

```
                   agent {
                        docker {
                             image 'myUbuntuImage:latest'
                             args '-u root --privileged'
                        }
                    }
```

Can we do the same in scripted pipeline?
May be something like this (or is there any alternative?) -

```
node('myUbuntuImage:latest`){
    // your build commands
}
```

Comment: Have you read through [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation?  That covers a couple of common cases.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that documentation that really covers a couple of common cases but I found a simpler way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code which looks simple and clean. It is almost identical to what I expected.

```
node{
    withDockerContainer(args: '-some -arguents', image: 'myUbuntuImage:latest'){
        // your build steps
    }
}
```

See the doc here - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/